# Code to enter emoji's from mobile keyboard to run appium script

Tags: android, eclipse, appium

We are using Appium automation tool to automate the mobile application.
We need to write the script in eclipse that how to enter emoji's from mobile keyboard in eclipse.
Please help me to find the scripts to enter emoji's.

Comment: Is your query resolved?

Comment: I am trying to use that solution which you suggested me.I will update you soon.Thank you sir.

Comment: "io.appium.android.apis:id/edit" from where we should take this id.We are unable to use uiautomator to take id on device keyboard.

Comment: That would be the ID of the `EditText` or `TextBox` that you want to type in.

Comment: Yeah got it.Thanks again.But while running automation. Emoji s are not displaying
driver.findElement(By.id("io.appium.android.apis:id/edit")).sendKeys("");
I have used the above code in eclipse,But when i copy and paste any emoji in eclipse it is displaying in unrecognized format.

Comment: You will need to replace `io.appium.android.apis:id/edit` with the ID of the text box you are trying to type in. And the emoticons may not be displayed properly in Eclipse, but will work in the Android device.

Comment: Yeah I have replaced the id of the text box where i need to enter the emoji.
In device it is not working .Is there any other way to solve my problem..?

Comment: How about the second option I gave you? `driver.findElementByName("").click();`

Comment: Based on ByName we cant take by using uiautomator.
In uiautomator we can only take by using id,class and text.

Comment: Is there any other way..?and sorry for troubling you.

Comment: You can use UIAutomator to click on that button by text, putting in that emoticon unicode...

Answer (score 0):

You can `sendKeys` as you do to type normal text in an `EditText`. Emoticons are nothing but Unicode characters. Like "U+1F61" is for "". For example you can try:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("io.appium.android.apis:id/edit")).sendKeys("");
```

For more such characters you may refer the list here: [Emoticons (Unicode block)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticons_(Unicode_block))

Or if you want to type it using screen keyboard on the device, you may try to click on the keyboard keys like:

```
driver.findElementByName("").click();
```

Obviously after clicking on whatever keys that open up the emoticon mode of the keyboard and scrolling enough to make a particular key with the desired emoticon visible on the screen.